# Como tirar a borda de uma imagem como link

Tags: html, css, imagem, css-border

Oi, eu sei que parece um problema bobo, mas já tentei de tudo e procurei em tudo! Eu não consigo tirar essa borda da minha imagem.

```css
body {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}
a img {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
a {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
header{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.logo {
    background: url(https://img.icons8.com/) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo-radical"><a href="#">
            <img class="logo"></a></div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Rapaz seu problema é tão obvio que eu quase não vi rss*

Vc está colocando um `background-imagem` na tag `<img>`, então apesar da imagem renderizar, o `user-agente` do browser cria essa borda que seria o tamanho total da tag `<img>`.

A imagem é um elemento externo, de certa forma embedado no código, o conteúdo que renderiza dentro da imagem não está no HTML, a tag `<img>` é um *container* que vai receber e renderizar a imagem externa, além disso não é permitido outros elementos dentro da tag `<img>`, e por isso, assim como a tag `<input>` a tag `<img>` não tem tag de fechamento `</img>` Esse elementos são conhecidos como *void elements* https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vc quer usar um `background-image`, não coloque direto na tag `<img>`, coloque em uma tag `<span>` por exemplo, que tb é um elemento `inline` assim como a imagem.

> O atributo `SRC` especifica o URI para a imagem a ser incorporada. Sua sintaxe é a mesma do atributo `HREF` da tag `<A>`. `SRC` é obrigatório.

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html

A imagem que vc quer chamar na tag `<img>` sempre deve ser declarada pelo atributo `src=""` no próprio HTML, e não no CSS com a propriedade `background-image`. Além disso, o atributo `src=""` é obrigatório na tag `<img>` e não deve ser omitido em favor de um `background-image`

Comment: Perfeito! O problema é que eu queria colocar uma logo clicável que depois seria trocada por outra logo, pensei em fazer isso adicionando uma classe na tag <img> mas não deu certo, porem ao usar a tag <span> como sugerido deu certo! Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @Wingeds se vc acha que resolveu o problema considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas da resposta que vc escolher, assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. []´s

Answer (score 1):

Precisa remover a borda do link (`a`) e não da imagem ( `img`), por isso o seletor correto seria:

```
a {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
 }
```

```css
a {
   outline : none;
   border: none
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/officel/80/000000/download-2.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Eu removi a borda dos dois, da imagem e do link mas mesmo assim não funciona, eu estou usando uma classe para imagem pois pretendo alterar ela através do js, mas parece que essa borda não sai de jeito nenhum :/

Comment: esse código funciona para mim, então para te ajudar melhor precisa replicar exatamente o seu problema, consegue fazer isso colocando o código com a imagem aqui no site?

Comment: Pronto, coloquei uma imagem